# Flutter Text Widget doesn't allow non nullable string param

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

This is a code that throws the error:

```dart
class DogName extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;

  const DogName(this.name);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.lightBlueAccent
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text(name),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the error is the following

[image: Error]

Could you please, I'm just refresing my Flutter knowledge

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make nullable data use `dataType?`. Another issue is you are reading `name` on runtime, therefore `DecoratedBox` cant be const because of `name` variable.

```dart
class DogName extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;

  const DogName(this.name);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.lightBlueAccent
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text(name),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But it would be better if you use named constructor with key,

```dart
class DogName extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  const DogName({
    Key? key,
    required this.name,
  }) : super(key: key);

 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text(name),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now if you want nullable, you need to provide default value means when `name` will get null.

```dart
class DogName extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? name;
  const DogName({
    Key? key,
    this.name,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text(name ?? "default value"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

More about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Answer (score 1):

You should write your widget as follow

```dart
class DogName extends StatelessWidget {

  const DogName(this.name);
  final String name;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.lightBlueAccent
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text(name),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Basically you can't define you Text widget as a constant because the `name` property isn't constant.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the const keyword at line 6. The name variable here is not const

Change your class to

```dart
class DogName extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;

  const DogName(this.name);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text(name),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```